# Line Break in Tikz Arrow Label

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, labels, edge

---

My goal is that, in the image shown below, that the label `below` appear on the line below `above;`, directly under `above;`.  I've used `\\` (and some other ideas) to try to achieve this (as shown in the code below), but the things I've tried do not achieve my goal.

---

[image: Image Generated by TeXWorks]

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\begin{document} 
\tikzset{-stealth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm and 5cm, semithick, ->,>=stealth']
\node[state, initial] (0) {$q_0$};
\path
    (0) edge[loop above] node { $above;\\below$ } (0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I'm using TeXworks Version 0.6.5 (MiKTeX 21.1).

---

Comment: You could try `{\parbox{1cm}{\textit{above};\\ \textit{below}}}` in place of the node text you currently have. Note that maths mode shouldn't be used for italics. Either use `\textit` if your intention is italic words or `\mathit` if your intention is a multi-letter variable name in italics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `align`  node option like this: `node[align=left] { above;\\ below }`. I suppose also that the words "above" and "below" don't have to be in math mode so they are not enclosed between two `$`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\begin{document} 
\tikzset{-stealth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm and 5cm, semithick, ->,>=stealth']
\node[state, initial] (0) {$q_0$};
\path
    (0) edge[loop above] node[align=left] { above;\\ below } (0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Your suggestion works.